# what is this "Scroll" on safari dev tool?

Tags: browser, safari

[image: safari dev tool]

What is this "Scroll" on safari dev tool?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a hit, if the Container is scrollable.

Comment: What does ti mean to look like a hit?